# Complexity of trominoes algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, master-theorem

What is or what should be complexity of (divide and conquer) trominoes algorithm and why?

I've been given a 2^k * 2^k sized board, and one of the tiles is randomly removed making it a deficient board. The task is to fill the with "trominos" which are an L-shaped figure made of 3 tiles.

Tiling Problem

– Input: A n by n square board, with one of the 1 by 1 square
missing, where n = 2k for some k ≥ 1.

– Output: A tiling of the board using a tromino, a three square tile
obtained by deleting the upper right 1 by 1 corner from a 2 by 2
square.

– You are allowed to rotate the tromino, for tiling the board.
Base Case: A 2 by 2 square can be tiled.

Induction:

– Divide the square into 4, n/2 by n/2 squares.

– Place the tromino at the “center”, where the tromino does not
overlap the n/2 by n/2 square which was earlier missing out 1 by 1
square.

– Solve each of the four n/2 by n/2 boards inductively.

Comment: You should probably provide the algorithm as well, or at least a link to a simple description of it.

Comment: Please be more specific about the second-to-last step "Place the tromino at the “center”, where the tromino does not overlap the n/2 by n/2 square which was earlier missing out 1 by 1 square." - you also could include the reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tromino

Comment: When you have a board divied into 4 parts, in one part you have missing tile. You are putting one part of tromino in each of the other parts. For example if you have missing tile in first part you are putting tromino elements in the second part on left-bottom place, third part on left-top place and fourth part on right-top place.

Comment: To you mean four smaller boards of *half size* or of *half the side length*, which would be *one fourth of size*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This algorithm runs in time O(n<sup>2</sup>) = O(4<sup>k</sup>). To see why, notice that your algorithm does O(1) work per grid, then makes four subcalls to grids whose width and height of half the original size. If we use n as a parameter denoting the width or height of the grid, we have the following recurrence relation:

> T(n) = 4T(n / 2) + O(1)

By the Master Theorem, this solves to O(n<sup>2</sup>). Since n = 2<sup>k</sup>, we see that n<sup>2</sup> = 4<sup>k</sup>, so this is also O(4<sup>k</sup>) if you want to use k as your parameter.

We could also let N denote the total number of squares on the board (so N = n<sup>2</sup>), in which case the subcalls are to four grids of size N / 4 each. This gives the recurrence

> S(N) = 4S(N / 4) + O(1)

This solves to O(N) = O(n<sup>2</sup>), confirming the above result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks wrong: the board is divided into `4`, so it should be `T(n) = 4T(n / 4) + O(1)`. The subgrids are 1/4 the original size, not half.

Comment: The subgrids are indeed of `1/4` the original size, but the side length is `n/2`. The recurrence is expressed in terms of the side length of the board, not the size of the board.

Comment: @Codor - maybe, but the answer is not at all clear about that, especially since it says "four subcalls to grids of half the original size". If you say grid **size**, that does not imply just the side length.

Comment: @IVlad Yes indeed, the formulation is a bit unclear.

Comment: @IVlad I've updated the answer to more clearly define what n is. I've also done a second analysis using N = n^2 as the total number of squares. Let me know if this looks better!

Comment: @templatetypedef - it does :) +1.

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding, the complexity can be determined as follows. Let `T(n)` denote the number of steps needed to solve a board of side length `n`. From the description in the original question above, we have

```
T(2) = c
```

where `c` is a constant and

```
T(n) = 4*T(n/2) + b
```

where `b` is a constant for placing the tromino. Using the [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem), the runtime bound is

```
O(n^2)
```

via case 1.

Comment: That recursion is `O(n^2)` actually.

Comment: @IVlad Thanks for the comment, I somehow mixed it up. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to offer less formal solutions but without making use of the Master theorem.

> – Place the tromino at the “center”, where the tromino does not overlap the n/2 by n/2 square which was earlier missing out 1 by 1 square.

I'm guessing this is an `O(1)` operation? In that case, if `n` is the board size:

```
T(1) = O(1)
T(n) = 4T(n / 4) + O(1) = 
     = 4(4T(n / 4^2) + O(1)) + O(1) = 
     = 4^2T(n / 4^2) + 4*O(1) + O(1) =
     = ... =
     = 4^kT(n / 4^k) + 4^(k - 1)*O(1)
```

But `n = 2^k x 2^k = 2^(2k) = (2^2)^k = 4^k`, so the whole algorithm is `O(n)`.

Note that this does not contradict @Codor's answer, because he took `n` to be the side length of the board, while I took it to be the entire area.

If the middle step is not `O(1)` but `O(n)`:

```
T(n) = 4T(n / 4) + O(n) =
     = 4(4*T(n / 4^2) + O(n / 4)) + O(n) =
     = 4^2T(n / 4^2) + 2*O(n) = 
     = ... =
     = 4^kT(n / 4^k) + k*O(n)
```

We have:

```
k*O(n) = n log n because 4^k = n
```

So the entire algorithm would be `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You do O(1) work per tromino placed. Since there's (n^2-1)/3 trominos to place, the algorithm takes O(n^2) time.